# Create a list of files inside a folder in Excel

Tags: command-line, batch

I have a folder with some files inside. I'd like to use a command from windows command prompt which shall list all the files within my folder in an Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to create a list of files in Excel from the command prompt

```
dir /A-D /B > yourfilename.csv
```

Replace *yourfilename* with your preferred file name.

This command will create a CSV file (which is editable in Excel). Once you have access to the CSV file you can save it as *.xls* format when you save it